# ASP.NET Newbie - can't update DataGrid from SQL database

Tags: asp.net, sql, datagrid

I'm completely new to ASP.NET and am trying to pull together a simple web app that would allow users to view (for now just that) data from a SQL database based on their selections from a ListBox and a Dropdown. The idea is that a click on a button after selections are made would return database results based on a stored proc that is being passed List and Dropdown selections as parameters. I think I'm pretty close but I can't seem to return the results into the DataGrid designated for that purpose. The C# code I'm running is below. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Timeline_Analytics_App_Test
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string Host = ListBox1.SelectedValue;
            string Test = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
            this.SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = "EXEC dbo.TEST_RESULT_DETAIL '" + Host + "', " + Test;
            //MessageBox.Show(this.SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand);
            //this.GridView1.DataBind();

            String queryString = SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand;

            MessageBox.Show(queryString);

            DataSet ds = GetData(queryString);

            if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("1");
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                //MessageBox.Show("2");
                GridView1.DataBind();
                //MessageBox.Show("3");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to the database.");
            }

        }

        DataSet GetData(String queryString)
        {

            // Retrieve the connection string stored in the Web.config file.
            String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Timeline_AnalyticsConnectionString3"].ConnectionString;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                // Connect to the database and run the query.
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);

                // Fill the DataSet.
                adapter.Fill(ds);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // The connection failed. Display an error message.
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to the database.");
            }

            return ds;
        }
    }
}
```

Add-on:

My default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/TATRRT.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Timeline_Analytics_App_Test.Default" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

    <%--Host List Box--%>
    <div>
        <h4 style="font-family:verdana; font-size:10pt; position:absolute;left:10px;top:140px">Please select the host you want to review</h4>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" style="font-family:verdana; font-size:10pt; position:absolute;left:10px;top:180px"
            DataTextField="Host" DataValueField="Host" Height="150" Width="320"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Timeline_Analytics_App_TestConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT Host FROM Test_Summary WHERE Category IS NULL AND Responsive = 1">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br></br>
    </div>

   <%--Test Dropdown--%>
    <div>
        <h4 style="font-family:verdana; font-size:10pt; position:absolute;left:350px;top:140px">Please select the test you want to review</h4>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" style="font-family:verdana; font-size:10pt; position:absolute;left:350px;top:180px"
            DataTextField="Test_Name" DataValueField="Test_Name" Width="320">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Timeline_Analytics_App_TestConnectionString2 %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT CAST(RIGHT(REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE(Test_Name), 8)), 2) AS INT) AS Test_Name FROM Test_Summary ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(REVERSE(RIGHT(REVERSE(Test_Name), 8)), 2) AS INT)"> 
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <%--Test Result Summary--%>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            style="font-family:verdana; font-size:10pt; position:absolute;left:10px;top:350px" AllowPaging="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <%--DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"--%>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Timeline_AnalyticsConnectionString3 %>" 
        SelectCommand="">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Retrieve results" 
        style="font-family:verdana; font-size:10pt; position:absolute;left:680px;top:180px" 
        onclick="Button1_Click"/>

</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Where is the definition of your GridView in your markup? Also, is the data coming back from the database correctly; in other words does the DataSet get filled or does any error occur?

Comment: are you getting any error messages?

Comment: There aren't any errors being thrown as of this code iteration - messages within the if - else condition print w/o issues. I tested the sproc with the exact parameters as those I'm using to test the app and it does indeed return results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and you have no `Columns` defined in your markup, thus when the `GridView` data binds it has nothing to bind to.

The easiest fix is to set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `True`, like this:

```
AutoGenerateColumns="True"
```

Note: This will make your column names the same as the database field, which may or may not be what you want.

To get more control over the `GridView` columns, then check out [GridView Column Property MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx)

Comment: Karl - thank you so much! This seems to have done the trick, my grid is populating right now! Also, this being my first post to Stack Overflow (although I've used it in past for reference), I wanted to thank everybody who took interest in my question - while I know this won't always be the case, I do greatly appreciate the speed with which this was resolved! Thanks again!!!

Comment: No problem, good luck with your GridView code. If you feel this answer helped you, then feel free to accept it.